# Emular evento push en Chrome

Tags: pwa

tengo un problema con el emulador de eventos push de Chrome, en versiones anteriores bastaba con ir a la pestaña Application en las Chrome Dev tools y presionar el botón push en las service workers, pero ahora me aparece una especie de input y luego el botón push, alguien me podría decir que tengo que introducir en ese input para poder emular el evento push?

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, me gustaría saber si ha habido alguna actualización con las Chrome Devtools o como verificar el correcto funcionamiento de las mismas, por mi parte instale Chrome Canary y Chrome Beta y presentaron el mismo detalle, sin embargo el botón sync funciona perfectamente pero el push no emite el evento al Service Worker.
Edge trae un emulador similar y su evento Push si es emitido a diferencia del de Chrome